# Missing divider for disabled rows in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView in my app. It only show data so I want the rows to be disabled. But with the config shown below in the adapter the ListView show no divider between rows. How can I fix it?

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return true;
}
```

Note: also tried

```
@Override
public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah...dividers will be disabled when you disable the row...because dividers are attched with rows by default..:)

Comment: Maybe you can try to disable the onClick from the listview